# Why setSystemCursor() isn't working (libgdx)?

Tags: libgdx

I'm making my own level editor and I want to change the cursor to a hand when the spacebar is pressed:

```
@Override
public boolean keyDown(InputEvent event, int keycode) {
    switch (keycode) {
    case Input.Keys.SPACE:
        System.out.println("Spacebar is pressed");
        Gdx.graphics.setSystemCursor(Cursor.SystemCursor.Hand);
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(InputEvent event, int keycode) {
    switch (keycode) {
    case Input.Keys.SPACE:
        Gdx.graphics.setSystemCursor(Cursor.SystemCursor.Arrow);
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But it doesn't work and I don't know why... What I am doing wrong?

Comment: When you say "It doesn't work", what do you mean? Do you get an error? Does keyDown not get called? Does it not detect the space key?

Comment: When press the spacebar it prints 'Spacebar is pressed', but the cursor doesn't change, and I don't get any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Libgdx wiki page](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Cursor-visibility-&-catching) it requires LWJGL3 backend:

> You can also change the cursor to a system cursor, this only works in the 
>   LWJGL3 backend and in the GWT backend. It can be done as follows:
>
> ```
> Gdx.graphics.setSystemCursor(SystemCursor.Crosshair);
> ```

Following is taken from the original [issue](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/3673):

> You can easily switch out the LWJGL 2 backend for the LWJGL 3 backend
>   in Gradle. In your core projects dependencies, change:
>
> ```
> compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl3:$gdxVersion"
> ```
>
> Make sure gdxVersion is set to the latest snapshot version 1.7.3-SNAPSHOT.
>   In your desktop launcher, simply replace LwjglApplicationConfiguration
>   and LwjglApplication with Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration and
>   Lwjgl3Application